# How to uninstall JDK on Mac OS?

Tags: java, macos, java-8, java-10

Folks - I am facing challenges while trying to uninstall JDK from my MAC (macOS High Sierra Version 10.13.4 - 17E199). I have two JDK instances installed and I want to uninstall both of them.

I am following the steps listed on this page: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/install/mac_jdk.html

I am trying to run this command in the /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines directory which throws an error that I do not have the permission.

```
rm -rf jdk1.8.0_06.jdk
```

I am the administrator of the machine and am not sure what more permission do I need. I have made attempts as the admistrator and as the root user with no success.

Please share your thoughts on this.

Comment: You tried `sudo rm -rf jdk1.8.0_06.jdk` ?

Comment: This would better fit on superuser.com or maybe https://apple.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 65, accepted):

From the [official Oracle manual](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/install/mac_jdk.html).

> Navigate to `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines` and remove the directory whose name matches the following format:
>
> ```
> /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdkmajor.minor.macro[_update].jdk
> ```
>
> For example, to uninstall 8u6:
>
> ```
> %rm -rf jdk1.8.0_06.jdk
> ```
>
> Do not attempt to uninstall Java by removing the Java tools from `/usr/bin`. This directory is part of the system software and any changes will be reset by Apple the next time you perform an update of the OS.

To remove system files you need to add sudo before rm -rf command.

Comment: I tried it and it works. But this way is not recommended by Oracle

Comment: @alexvipul - This is *exactly* the way recommended by Oracle.  The above is a quote from the Oracle manual.  It doesn't suggest any alternative ways.

Comment: There's a way to switch default jdk on mac os : https://www.codevoila.com/post/78/how-to-uninstall-or-remove-jdk-in-mac-os-x

Comment: @StephenC let me double check

Answer (score 17):

For MacOS - Big Sur | Using Terminal

I was able to remove OpenJDK as per information provided in below link.

[Site Link](https://actonnotes.wordpress.com/2020/11/22/how-to-remove-openjdk-version-15-on-apple-macos/)

[image]

Comment: This one should mark as answer :D

Answer (score 9):

If you want to remove JDK from mac you can use the following command:

```
cd /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/
```

and then use sudo to remove the jdk because you need root permissions to delete jdk from /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/. 
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/ is owned by root.

```
sudo rm -rf jdk1.8.0_06.jdk
```

https://installvirtual.com/uninstall-java-8-mac-os-x/

Answer (score 6):

This answer is correct for JDK 8, but it would be nice to point out that Oracle provides different instructions for each release of the JDK. The link structure changes slightly for some versions, but generally you can go to https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase, select your JDK release, and look for the "Install Guide" link in the Overview group.

For example:

- [JDK 9](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/install/installation-jdk-and-jre-macos.htm#JSJIG-GUID-F9183C70-2E96-40F4-9104-F3814A5A331F)
- [JDK 10](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/install/installation-jdk-and-jre-macos.htm#JSJIG-GUID-F9183C70-2E96-40F4-9104-F3814A5A331F)
- [JDK 11](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/install/installation-jdk-macos.html#GUID-F9183C70-2E96-40F4-9104-F3814A5A331F)

Also, the files in /usr/bin are *not* part of the JDK, so you don't really want to remove them. On a system that has never had the JDK installed:

```
$ ls -l /usr/bin/java
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  74 Sep 27 17:08 /usr/bin/java -> /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/Current/Commands/java

$ java -version
No Java runtime present, requesting install.
```

Apparently macOS includes a baseline version of the JDK, where each command is a stub that just prints this message and pops up a dialog in the GUI.