# Installing rJava on macOS Catalina 10.15.6

Tags: java, r, macos, rjava

After many infuriating tries getting rJava to work, I've decided to do an Q&A of how I finally got it to work.

How do I install rJava on my MacOS system? I use macOS Catalina 10.15.6.

I frequently get warning messages of the type:

> Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘rJava’:
> .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'rJava', details:
> call: dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...)
> error: unable to load shared object >'/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/library/rJava/libs/rJava.so':
> dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/library/rJava/libs/rJava.so, >6): Library not loaded: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk->11.0.1.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/server/libjvm.dylib
> Referenced from: >/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/library/rJava/libs/rJava.so
> Reason: image not found

I've previously tried installing different JDK (Java Development Kit) from Oracle.
I get the warning that RStudio only wants to work together with JDK-11.0.1.
To download this I would need to create an Oracle account.

Comment: as well as installing the JDK creating a free account might be worth it to get java running, have you tried `install.packages(rJava, dependencies = TRUE)`

Comment: https://www.owsiak.org/r-java-11-and-making-sure-you-can-load-rjava/

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to solve this issue through the following steps:

1. Remove the package rJava.
   In the R console, enter:

```
rm.packages("rJava")
```

2. Remove previous attempts to install Java on your MacOS by entering the following in the *terminal*:

```
sudo rm -fr /Library/PreferencePanes/JavaControlPanel.prefPane 
sudo rm -fr /Library/Application\ Support/Oracle/Java
```

Solution to remove unwanted previous version: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50056979/11550980

```
sudo rm -fr /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdkmajor.minor.macro[_update].jdk
```

3. Install OpenJDK ready for production: JDK 14.0.2

http://jdk.java.net/14/

If installing manually, unpack the .tar.gz file and place the unpacked folder in:
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/

4. Control in the terminal:

```
java -version
```

5. In the R Console:

```
install.packages("rJava")
```

6. You may have to reconfigure R to work with your version of Java. In the *terminal*:

```
R CMD javareconf
```

Comment: In the past, I've had to `sudo R CMD javareconf` for it to work properly in step 6, just in case it doesn't work without `sudo`.